# Why isn't the Python shape matching what Keras is expecting?

Tags: python, keras

In my code, I have: `self._model.predict(next_state)`

When I `print(next_state.shape)`, I get `(14,)`

But when I run my code, I get an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_4_input to have shape (14,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

`model.summary` is:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 24)                360       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 24)                600       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 100       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,060
Trainable params: 1,060
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: Can you provide your `model.summary`, please?

Comment: @R.yan updated with the summary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model expects your input array to have the shape of (examples X features). Thats why the input and output shapes are described by `(None, 24)` where 'None' denotes the batch size. Thus the first axis denotes the different examples you want to predict as rows, with their features as columns. The keras API requires arrays indexed with two-dimensional positional arguments, while you are providing it with a single-digit indexed array `(14, )`.

To process a single example, an easy workaround is to reshape the array to have two positional indicators before sending for prediction:

`self._model.predict(np.reshape(next_state, [1, next_state.shape]))`

Which changes your input to `(1, 14)`, which is required by the model denoted by `(None, 14)`

Comment: But the error I'm getting is: `expected dense_4_input to have shape (14,) but got array with shape (1,)`. So aren't I giving the model what it expects?

Comment: Also it gives an error: `TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: No you are not. Keras omits the first dimension, the batch size, since this is determined at runtime. So when it says it expects `(14, )`, it actually expects the second dimension (your number of features) to be equal to 14. So to pass 1 data example, you need to give it a batch size of 1, with 14 dimensions, or `(1, 14)`

Comment: I'll need more information on your code for the second comment.